# Startup Parameters for component Data in Hybrid fiori App

Tags: sapui5, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am using SCP web IDE full stack and imported standard fiori app for leave request and changed the coded for development purposes, I have the replaced the Component.js to extend `UIComponent` instead of `sap.ca.scfld.md.ComponentBase`, and I have also created index.html for the app with the properties of component data as:

```
new sap.m.Shell({

app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({

height : "100%",

name : "hcm.myleaverequest",

settings : {

componentData: {startupParameters: oStartupParameters}

},
```

After I build the packaged app and install on the device and debug, I am unable to get the  startup parameters  where in the controller `S1` I am getting `sap.ui.component(c).getComponentData().startupParameters` as undefined, where as when I run it on the local via index.html and Component.js, the app is working fine.

How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you assign oStartupParameters like this:
     `var oStartupParameters = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().mParams;`

as seen at the very end of this blog:
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3869909

Comment: I have assigned the following in index.html but still when installed on the phone this.getComponentData().startupParameters is returning undefined